# What happens to MySQL when hitting 100% CPU usage?

Tags: mysql, database

I am running a MySQL server on RDS (AWS) and I fired 5 INSERT queries into the database which take about 2 minutes to complete each one. The server is at 100% CPU which was to be expected but is this a bad thing? The MySQL server is still serving requests absolutely fine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is a bad thing. when you're using your 100% percent of CPU, the MySQL still will answer your request but in client side takes too much time and users will experience slow connection due to queue on request to lock and release. 
I suggest you that you can divide and run this heavy jobs on small jobs. or run when your system load is low for example in midnights.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would still like to know a more in depth answer.